# Matrix multiplication in BlueJ (Java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, matrix-multiplication, multiplication, bluej

can anyone find me the mistake in the following code?

This is the multiplication of matrices that contain fractions. It shows me a NullPointerException and underscores the line with z[i][j].
The scitaj and vynasob methods are already tested and the error should not be there. I am attaching a picture. If you need to see a larger part of the code for understanding, tell me.

Thank you very much :)

matica - matrix
zlomok - fraction
nasobenie, vynasob - multiplication
PocetRiadkov - number of rows
PocetStlpcov - number of columns
scitaj - +

```
public Matica nasobenie() {
    Matica xs = new Matica(new Zlomok[][]
    {
        {new Zlomok(1, 1), new Zlomok(2, 1), new Zlomok(3, 1)},
        {new Zlomok(4, 1), new Zlomok(5, 1), new Zlomok(6, 1)}
    });
        
    Matica ys = new Matica(new Zlomok[][]
        {
            {new Zlomok(7, 1), new Zlomok(8, 1)},
            {new Zlomok(9, 1), new Zlomok(10, 1)},
            {new Zlomok(11, 1), new Zlomok(12, 1)}
        });
    
    Zlomok [][] z = new Zlomok[xs.getPocetRiadkov()][ys.getPocetStlpcov()];
    System.out.println(z);
    for (int i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < z[0].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < xs.getPocetStlpcov(); k++) {
                z[i][j] = z[i][j].scitaj(xs.getPrvok(i, k).vynasob(ys.getPrvok(k, j)));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    Matica vysledok = new Matica(z);
    return vysledok;        
}
```

Comment: Please, don't put code as images. The line is throwing a NPE because there's nothing at `0,0` for the matrix. The first value is in `1,1`

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you please relevant code into the question, please? No external links.

Comment: `z[i][j]` is `null`, not a value representing zero, you cannot call `scitaj` on it until a proper value has been assigned

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo I'm not clear why you'd expect there to be a value at `1,1`?

Comment: That's what your code says, the first value is at `1,1` and not at `0,0`. The `for` is starting from `0`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 1,1 and 0,0. But as @harold said, there was a problem with scitaj method. I added a for loop to fill in z and it works. Thank you.

Comment: What you have explained in your last answer reflects exactly what I was saying. The matrix was empty at `0,0` and you were trying to use a method over a null value, when getting it from `0,0`. By filling the matrix, what you did is added a value at `0,0`, therefore, it's not failing anymore